# Why is it benificial to split initiative pool on Decisive attacks?

Tags: attack, exalted-3e

I have noticed a few charms that have some variation of the same mechanics, but I don't understand why it is beneficial.

One example: Thousand Razor Wind (Dragon Blooded p278)

The mechanic lets you do more than one decisive attack against the same foe, and you then split the initiative damage pool among all the attacks rounding down.

My question is what makes this desirable? Or maybe in what cases/strategies would this be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching more my conclusion is that this is some reasons that it might be good to split the attack:

- Onslaught penalties
- Synergies with other charms that boost damage for each attack, one proposal was Winter Fangs Attach where you drain(essence)initiative from your enemy with each attack, and now you can do it multiple times.
- Things that trigger on each attack, for instance, an artifact that is always poisoned, this effect would now be applied multiple times.
- Enemies might have charms that let them stop one attack, but if you have more they have less defensive measures that work on the second. So my having repeated attack on the same enemy that later ones are more likely to get through.